# Drupal 7 :Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '

Tags: php, module, drupal-7, drupal-modules, hook-menu

im new in drupal 7.
I created a custom module in Drupal 7 "audit_pdf" for Extranet.
In this module i created a sub-module "audit" who display a custom form.
The form is in audit.pages.inc
The audit_menu in audit.module

**audit.module**

```
function audit_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['audit'] = array(
      'title' => 'Audit',
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      'access arguments' => array('administer audit'),
      'page callback' => 'audit_form',
      'page arguments' => array('audit_form'),
      'file' => 'audit.page.inc',
    );
    return $items;
}

function audit_permission() {
  $permissions = array(
    'administer audit' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer audit'),
    ),  
  );
  return $permissions;  
}
```

**audit.pages.inc**

```
function audit_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form = array();
    $form['title'] = array(
      '#prefix' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-3">',
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Title'),
      '#collapsible' => FALSE, 
      '#collapsed' => FALSE,
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
     '#type' => 'submit',
     '#value' =>t('Valider'),
    );
    return $form;
}
```

**audit.info**

```
name = Audit
description = Download pdf after write

core = 7.x

package = My Module

project = "audit_pdf"


files[] = audit.module

files[] = audit.pages.inc

files[] = audit.admin.inc

files[] = audit.controller.inc
```

**I put 'file' => 'audit.page.inc'**

But I have this message

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/../audit_pdf/Audit/audit.page.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /**/aidopc_user/aidopc.fr/extranet/includes/menu.inc on line 525*

Comment: Did you clear the Drupal's cache ? `/admin/config/development/performance`

Comment: It's working ! thank's